# how to binding data json in nativescript angular without interface class?

Tags: angular, nativescript

i try to binding data in nativescript angular. at console i got json data but i can't binding to html, any one can help me?

this my console log

```
[
{
  id:1,
  name:jonathan,
  status:y
},
{
  id:2,
  name:hendra,
  status:y
},
{
  id:3,
  name:jarjit,
  status:y
   }
]
```

this my service

```
userList(){
    let headers = this.createRequestHeader();
    return this.http.get(this.warehouseUrl, { headers: headers });
}
private createRequestHeader() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type"  : "application/json",
        "Authorization" : "Basic " + this.Authorization
     });
    return headers;
}
```

this my component

```
this.items = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.userList()
        .subscribe(
            (result:any) => {
                this.items = result;
                console.log(this.items);
            }
        )
}
```

and this one is my html

```
<StackLayout>
<ListView [items]="this.items" class="list-group">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
        <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/item', item.id]" [text]="item.name"
            class="list-group-item"></Label>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

please help me how to binding array json in nativescript angular

Answer (score -1):

`[items]="this.items"` just needs to be `[items]="items"`. You dont need to use the `this` reference in the html, just the variable name.

You also need to change your http call slightly, based on your package.json, you need to use `return this.http.get(this.warehouseUrl, { headers: headers }).pipe(map(res => res.json()));`. Using the import `import { map, timeout } from "rxjs/operators";`

Comment: im already change to be items but the result keep [object object]

Comment: i try second method with map but warning like "ERROR TypeError: res.json is not a
function"

Comment: @JonathanLogin did you add the map import?

Comment: import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable as RxObservable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse, HttpParams } from "@angular/common/http";

Comment: this my package json
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "~6.0.0",
  "@angular/common": "~6.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~6.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "~6.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~6.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "~6.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~6.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~6.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "~6.0.0",
  "nativescript-angular": "~6.0.0",
  "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
  "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
  "rxjs": "~6.1.0",
  "tns-core-modules": "~4.1.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
 },

Comment: when i binding with this code... i got first array

<Label [text]="items[0].name" ></Label>

Comment: @JonathanLogin it just needs to be `item.name`, items is the array but item is the entry

Comment: i got warning this : Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'